# What is this type of search called and what is the best way to approach it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a column in my postgresql database that stores titles such as: "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", etc.  Currently, I'm using elasticsearch to search the database.

1)  Is there already a search analyzer in elasticsearch that will allow me to search using search terms such as "Title One", "Title I", "Title Two", "Title II", etc. even though "One", "I", "Two", "II", etc. would not be stored in the database?
2)  What is this type of searching called?  Are there already well defined search techniques for doing this, and if so, what are they called? (Natural language search?)

Answer (score 3):

ElasticSearch support synonyms, but these have to be defined manually:

```
"filter" : {
                "synonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                }
            }
```

Take a look: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html